# ERROR Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'temp') TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'temp')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, redux, redux-toolkit

So this is my code (`react`, `redux-toolkit`) and I am getting that error.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import styles from "./styles.module.css";
import { getCurrentWeather } from "../../Redux/Reducers/currentWeatherSlice";
import { getUserPosition } from "../../Redux/Reducers/userPositionSlice";

// URLFor the icons
// https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/${}.pngs

function CurrentWeather() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const currentWeather = useSelector(
    (state) => state.currentWeather.currentWeather
  );
  const userPosition = useSelector((state) => state.userPosition.userPosition);

  const [query, setQuery] = useState("");
  const [x, setX] = useState(null);
  const [y, setY] = useState(null);

  //Get user's Position
  useEffect(() => {
    const successHandler = (position) => {
      setX(position.coords.latitude);
      setY(position.coords.longitude);
    };
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successHandler);

    if (x && y !== null) {
      dispatch(getUserPosition({ x, y }));
    }
  }, [dispatch, x, y]);

  const handleCitySearch = (e) => {
    setQuery(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleForm = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  };

  const handleCityFetch = () => {
    dispatch(getCurrentWeather(query));
    setQuery("");
  };

  console.log(userPosition);

  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <h1>CurrentWeather</h1>
      <div className={styles.currentWeather_container}>
        <div className={styles.input_container}>
          <form onSubmit={handleForm} className={styles.form}>
            <input
              value={query}
              type="text"
              placeholder="Search City"
              onChange={handleCitySearch}
            />
            <button onClick={handleCityFetch}>Go</button>
          </form>
        </div>

        <div className={styles.top_section}>
          {x && y && userPosition && (
            <>
              <div>
                <p>{userPosition.name}</p>
                <p>{userPosition.visibility}</p>
              </div>
              <div>
                <span>{userPosition?.main.temp}</span>
                <span>°C</span>
              </div>
            </>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default CurrentWeather;
```

Even though it works as expected with the `userPosition.name` when I try to render `userPosition.main.temp` I'm getting the error.

I am  not sure if its a redux state problem or that I'm trying to render before I get the data (even though it seems that I do have the data).

I've  tried multiple solutions such as moving the state for the `userPosition` to its own slice, using the Optional Chaining operator on `userPosition`, also I had a bunch of console logs everywhere but I can't find my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've placed the null-check on the wrong object. The error is informing you that `userPosition.main` is undefined. This access is fine though, same as `userPosition.name` and `userPosition.visibility`. No error is thrown since `userPosition` is defined. The issue arises when `userPosition.main` is undefined and the code attempts to access the `temp` property

```js
{x && y && userPosition && (
  <>
    <div>
      <p>{userPosition.name}</p>       // ok, value is undefined
      <p>{userPosition.visibility}</p> // ok, value is undefined
    </div>
    <div>
      <span>
        {userPosition?.main.temp}  // not ok, accessing undefined object
      </span>
      <span>°C</span>
    </div>
  </>
)}
```

Since the code has already checked above that to ensure `userPosition` is truthy, move the null-check onto the potentially null/undefined `main` property.

```js
{x && y && userPosition && (
  <>
    <div>
      <p>{userPosition.name}</p>       // ok, value is undefined
      <p>{userPosition.visibility}</p> // ok, value is undefined
    </div>
    <div>
      <span>
        {userPosition.main?.temp}  // ok, value is undefined or temp
      </span>
      <span>°C</span>
    </div>
  </>
)}
```